# Apache tomcat installation in Google cloud compute engine

Tags: apache, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

I followed every step correctly in this website. (http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/googlecloud/installing-apache-tomcat-on-google-cloud ) 
I searched a lot. Other's solutions also doesn't work. I don't know what to do. Any ideaa? 
The problem is I can't see the port 8080 so tomcat runs

Comment: The issue is that you "assume" that you followed every step "correctly". You evidently did not. Edit your question with details so that we can have help.

Comment: Could you provide more details ? The service doesn't start ? Is it the wrong port ? what the result of command `netstat -tlnp` ? What's your VM config ? your OS?

Comment: netstat -tlnp output is exactly as shown below:

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address       State       PID/Program n
ame
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1680/sshd    
   
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      9231/java    
   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      9231/java    
   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1680/sshd

Comment: My VM is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , Which is in Google Cloud Compute Engine, Fromfirewall rule I added Port 8080.

Comment: Something is listen the port 8080 on the VM. Did you try a `curl localhost:8080` to see what is it answered ? If it's Tomcat welcome page, the problem isn't on your VM, but on the network. Can you perform a describe of your firewall rule on the port 8080 and add the result here?

Comment: I overcame some issues. But solved issue comes with another issue. Finally , it work great. BUT, when I shutdown computer(Google Cloud VM) and open it again I need to start tomcat server again. I start the tomcat by typing <b>sh startup.sh</b> And it says successfully started but <b>curl localhost:8080 </b> output gives me index of apache 8080 port. Means that it works. But it doesn't give same output to <b>domain.com:8080 </b> so I hope firewall rule somehow stopped or doesn't work. Idk why.